# htaccess redirect with query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've url with a link parameter in it. I want redirect this to a php file.
How can I implement this using htaccess file?

> Source url: www.example.com/?id=15&L=1&link=androidapp
>
> Target url: www.example.com/test.php

I want to check if "link=androidapp" exists, then redirect to the php file.

I've tried the following code, but not working;

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^link=androidapp$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/test.php? [R=301,L]
```

Can you guys please help me to solve the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you skip the `^` and the `$` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} link=androidapp 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/test.php? [R=301,L]
```

The `^` means that the your pattern matches only from the beginning of the querystring, but your querystring begins with `id=15...`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} link=androidapp(&|$) 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/test.php? [R=301,L]
```