# htaccess: automatically redirecting to new url when condition comes true

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I am using htaccess rule on my website for example see the below rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|ar)/properties/$ search.php?lang=$1
```

this rule is working fine as the user visit http://domain.com/en/properties/

when user visit http://domain.com/search.php?lang=ar the htaccess automatically redirect it to the first link

is that possible? Any help in this regard is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362672/htaccess-redirect-with-query-string?answertab=active#tab-top          This Link, can help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example what you are looking for

```
RewriteEngine on
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /~account/$1 [L,R=301]

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /~account/$1/ [L,R=301]

# perform redirect if indiana.edu
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.indiana.edu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.iu.edu/~account/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or

```
# Permanent URL redirect -
Redirect 301 /search.php?lang=ar http://domain.com/en/properties/
```

Comment: I want to match this using regular expression because the link is dynamic means it has more than 1 parameters.

Comment: If you are using Wordpress You can try [This Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

Comment: No not using wordpress

Comment: I have Update the above answer please check It will WorK

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(en|ar)\/properties\/$ search.php?lang=$1
```